# JsonPath: return first find

Tags: jsonpath

I would like to retrieve only the first `name` ocurrence.

```
[
  {
    "name": "xx",
    "lastname": "yy",
    "child": [
      {
        "name": "x2"
      },
      {
        "name": "x3"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "yy",
    "lastname": "xz"}
]
```

with this regex: `$..name` the result is:

```
[
  "xx",
  "x2",
  "x3",
  "yy"
]
```

and with this `$..name[0]` is:

```
[
  "x",
  "x",
  "x",
  "y"
]
```

but **I'm looking for this result**:

```
[
  "xx"
]
```

Note: it have to be in only one regex, I can't store result to after manipulate it

Comment: Have a look at https://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/, you'll see that `$..name[0]` works for the [Nebhale implementation](https://github.com/nebhale/JsonPath). Based on the results you showed I suspect you are using Goessner's implementation. It might help to update the question to make this clear.

Comment: I was trying in [http://jsonpath.com/](http://jsonpath.com/), you site looks more complete. but that expression doesn't work for my implementation _Gatling_

Answer (score 2):

`$[0].name`

will give you the first match only:

```
[  
   "xx"
]
```

Comment: Go through how to write a correct [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)