# How to get first object from JSON array in Talend

Tags: arrays, json, object, talend

I have data in the MongoDB database where one of the columns is JSON Array. Now I want to retrieve only the first object from that JSON Array column.

Input_Column :

```
**[{"id" : "25",
"name" : "spot1" ,
"node" : "start_node", 
"order" : "1",
"status" : "completed", 
"location" : "gate1"},
{"name" : "spot2", 
"order" : "2" },
{ "name" : "spot3", 
"node" : "start_node", 
"status" : "pending" }]**
```

Required output_column :

```
 `status:`

 completed
```

I need only the first value from the array. I tried using the tExtractJSONFields component in Talend. And set the JSON loop as "$.status". But I got the output as

```
`status:`

completed
null
pending
```

AFTER EDIT :

```
[{"id" : "25",
"name" : "spot1" ,
"node" : "start_node", 
"order" : "1",
"status" : "completed" ,
"location" : "gate1"},
{"name" : "spot2", 
"order" : "2" },
{ "name" : "spot3", 
"node" : "start_node", 
"status" : "pending" } ]


[{"id" : "26",
"name" : "pull1" ,
"node" : "start_node", 
"order" : "3",
"status" : "arrived" ,
"location" : "gate3"},
{"name" : "pull2", 
"order" : "4" },
{ "name" : "pull3", 
"node" : "end_node", 
"status" : "pending" } ]

[{"id" : "27",
"name" : "task1" ,
"node" : "start_node", 
"order" : "5",
"status" : "pending" ,
"location" : "gate12"},
{"name" : "task2", 
"order" : "6" },
{ "name" : "task3", 
"node" : "end_node", 
"status" : "pending" } ]
```

expected output :

```
status 

completed
arrived
pending
```

Comment: Check this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47590235/jsonpath-return-first-find . it seems that your solution is in there (unvoted though)

Comment: @Corentin I tried "$[0].status" expression in tExtractJSOFields but I get only null values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this is not a valid json  you have post

I corrected your json to be like this

You can test it here : https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#

```json
[{"id" : "25",
"name" : "spot1" ,
"node" : "start_node", 
"order" : "1",
"status" : "completed" ,
"location" : "gate1"},
{"name" : "spot2", 
"order" : "2" },
{ "name" : "spot3", 
"node" : "start_node", 
"status" : "pending" } ]
```

Try to put your json in a file at first time
-> then in the **metadata**

[image]

--> drag & drop your file json (Metadata)

In your job just put this structure
[image]

javaFlex is configured as such
[image]

- In the advanced settings don't forget to put :

**import java.util.ArrayList;**

Output would be :

Starting job Test_ at 14:36 27/05/2021.
[statistics] connecting to socket on port 3903
[statistics] connected
**completed**
[statistics] disconnected

Job Test_ ended at 14:36 27/05/2021. [exit code  = 0]

Comment: I need to get the first value from status. How do I achieve that? status = completed

Comment: Just edited my answer ! this is how you could achieve it

Comment: Thank you so much. This works for one record. I have multiple records where the first element from all the JSON arrays must be retrieved.

Comment: Just adapt the method using the other columns and delete the first element

Comment: I have edited my ques, please check. Thanks

Comment: do you confirm that the json array is column ?  could you post your job desgin or describe how you are getting the json array ?  so that i can help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232955/discussion-between-pavithra-and-amine-ben-khelifa).